# WKT comparison?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How to compare 2 well known text points in javascript?
For example if the points are `a = POINT(78.067606 12.994332) , b=POINT(78.067606 12.994332) ,`
then if we compare `(a==b)` it gives false,instead of true .  Why?
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare WKT of points (that's just comparision of two strings):

```
var p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10.123, 10.456);
var p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10.123, 10.456);

var wkt1 = p1.toString();
var wkt2 = p2.toString();

if (wkt1 == wkt2)
    alert('Works as expected!');
```

Sometimes points may be very close to each other, but their coordinates may be slightly different. Another option is to control distance between geometries:

```
var p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10.123, 10.456);
var p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10.124, 10.457);

var allowedDist = 0.002;
var dist = p1.distanceTo(p2);

if (dist < allowedDist)
    alert('Points are close enough');
```